# Google Maps API MapFragment allocates a bunch of memory

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

It's seem like a bug. When I enable my location (by googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)) and do nothing, MapFragment still allocates a lot of object (Rect). 
It's not a leak because memory can be released normally, it is just an unneeded allocation
I can fix it by turning it off and everything works well. But anyone can figure out what happened? How can we fix it without disabling my location?

Here is the heap dump and memory graph.
Thanks a lot

[image]

[image]